# TFRecordReader in data input pipeline

Tags: python, queue, tensorflow

I'm currently stuck with an implementation problem of `TFRecordReader`

This is the setup :

```
trainQ = tf.train.string_input_producer(fileList)
RecReader = tf.TFRecordReader()
batch_strings = RecReader.read(trainQ)
con,seq=tf.parse_single_sequence_example(batch_strings.value,context_features=lengths_context,sequence_features=convo_pair,name='parse_ex')
encoder_inputs,decoder_inputs,enc_len,dec_len = seq['utterance'],seq['response'],con['utter_length'],con['resp_length']
mini_batch = tf.train.batch([encoder_inputs,decoder_inputs,enc_len,dec_len,decoder_inputs],batch_size,2,capacity=50*batch_size,dynamic_pad = True,enqueue_many=False)
encoder_inp,decoder_inp,encoder_lens,decoder_lens,labels = mini_batch
...
<build rest of the model>
...
loss = <some loss>
train_ops = <optimizer>.minimize(loss)
```

Now when I do `train_ops.run()`, it automatically reads off the queue and trains the model over a batch. But if I want to evaluate some intermediate variable, I cannot do `variable.eval()` since that would mean a new batch being read off the trainQ queue with different values

One way I can think of circumventing this to use a placeholder to feed `parse_single_example` and populating the placeholder in the train loop each time. But is there a better way of doing this i.e. evaluating variables without reading off the queue again?

Hope this is not confusing

Answer (score 0):

If you want to evaluate an intermediate layer (call it `conv3`) that depends on the batch input every 100 iterations, you can do the following:

```py
for step in range(100000):
    if step % 100 != 0:
        # only run the training operation
        sess.run(train_op)
    else:
        # run train_op AND `conv3` at the same time
        _, conv3_value = sess.run([train_op, conv3])
```

The trick here is to call `train_op` and `conv3` in the same call the `tf.Session`. That way, a batch is read off the training queue to train one step, but it is also used at the same time to compute `conv3`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I get that you can always output values in the same run(), but this way debugging will be tedious i.e. I'll have to output a whole bunch of intermediate values at a time rather than just evaluate them on the go. Is there any other 'elegant' solution?